# "Glitched" pixels, El Capitan, formula box in numbers

Tags: numbers, macos

Today I installed El Capitan on my Macbook Pro and noticed some weird graphical effects when I was editing my numbers document:

[image: Glitched pixels around numbers' formula box]

I know that this is entirely software-related, otherwise the screen shot tool couldn't have captured it, and it turns on and off randomly, with mouse-overs and hovers.

Does anyone know a possible cause and fix of this?

My Macbook:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
- Graphics Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB
- OSX El Capitan Version 10.11

My Display:

- Built-in Display
- 15.4-inch (2880 x 1800)
- Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

Comment: I have noticed a number of graphics related problems with El Capitan ranging from minor to severe (crashing).

Comment: What model, exactly, is your MacBook?

Comment: Hi there @Undo, I've added that info to the post ;)

Comment: You may want to submit a [bug report to Apple.](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html)

Comment: @bjbk I haven't noticed this behaviour since I posted the question; would you recommend I still report it? Or could there have been an automatic update in-between which fixed it?

Comment: I'd do it only if it comes back.  Like you said, update may have fixed it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it doesn't happen to me anymore so if anyone else is having this problem I'd recommend:

- restarting your computer (I did this)
- Updating your OS (I am updating every time as soon as a new update comes out)